# Why does this code fail to execute 'fetch'?

Tags: service-worker, push-api

I'm working on push notifications using service workers. I'm using the XHR(Ajax) approach to get my notification, here is a code snippet of service-worker.js:

```
 var API_ENDPOINT = new Request('/getNotification', {
redirect: 'follow'});

event.waitUntil(
    fetch(API_ENDPOINT, {credentials: 'include' })
        .then(function(response) {

            console.log(response);
            if (response.status && response.status != 200) {
                // Throw an error so the promise is rejected and catch() is executed
                throw new Error('Invalid status code from API: ' +
                    response.status);
            }
            // Examine the text in the response
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log('API data: ', data);

            var title = 'TEST';
            var message = data['notifications'][0].text;
            var icon = data['notifications'][0].img;

            // Add this to the data of the notification
            var urlToOpen = data['notifications'][0].link;

            var notificationFilter = {
                tag: 'Test'
            };

            var notificationData = {
                url: urlToOpen,
                parsId:data['notifications'][0].parse_id
            };

            if (!self.registration.getNotifications) {
                return showNotification(title, message, icon, notificationData);
            }

        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.error('A Problem occured with handling the push msg', err);

            var title = 'An error occured';
            var message = 'We were unable to get the information for this ' +
                'push message';

            return showNotification(title, message);
        })
);
```

This code works fine the first time I run the curl, but the second time I got an error in the console:

```
Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': Cannot construct a Request with a Request object that has already been used
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `API_ENDPOINT` has already consumed by the `fetch()`. You need a fresh request object each time you pass it to fetch so [clone it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/clone) before using it:

```
fetch(API_ENDPOINT.clone(), { credentials: 'include' })...
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved my issue ! 

For those who get an error like :

A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred
Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': Cannot construct a Request with a Request object that has already been used
It is because you probably use a service worker, then intercept fetch event and inside try to reperform a fetch just after on the same request because you cache hit failed. In that case, dont do fetch(request), but do instead : fetch(request.clone()), which creates a new request.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reuse the Request object multiple times, but do:

```
fetch('/getNotification', {
  credentials: 'include',
  redirect: 'follow'
})
```