# Error: Request object that has already been used

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, service-worker

### I keep getting this error in the console log

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': Cannot construct a Request with a Request object that has already been used.

I tried changing my service worker but it doesn't work

```js
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => event.waitUntil(preLoad()));

const preLoad = function () {
  return caches.open('cc-offline').then((cache) => {
    return cache.addAll(['/offline.html', '/index.html']);
  });
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(checkResponse(event.request).catch(function () {
    return returnFromCache(event.request)
  }));
  event.waitUntil(addToCache(event.request));
});

const checkResponse = (request) => {
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
    fetch(request).then((response) => {
      (response.status !== 404) ? fulfill(response) : reject()
    }, reject)
  });
};

const addToCache = (request) => {
  return caches.open('cc-offline').then((cache) => {
    return fetch(request).then((response) => {
      return cache.put(request, response);
    });
  });
};

const returnFromCache = (request) => {
  return caches.open('cc-offline').then((cache) => {
    return cache.match(request).then((matching) => {
      return (!matching || matching.status == 404) ? cache.match('offline.html') : matching
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch` don't allow you to use a request twice, at least at current version :). Using the same request object in both `checkResponse` and `addToCache` maybe the case. You can try to clone the request object before calling `fetch` as mention in here [Why does this code fail to execute 'fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394924/why-does-this-code-fail-to-execute-fetch)

Comment: I'm getting this now: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'clone' on 'Request': Request body is already used`

Comment: You can't clone a request that has already been used either.

`clone() throws a TypeError if the response Body has already been used. In fact, the main reason clone() exists is to allow multiple uses of Body objects (when they are one-use only.)`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/clone

Comment: any leads to solve  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'clone' on 'Request': Request body is already used