# how to solve service_worker_en.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

My Chrome console is giving this error for [my website](https://www.iusefaith.com/)

```
service_worker_en.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Cannot construct a Request with a Request object that has already been used.
```

I have read this article [on S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394924/why-does-this-code-fail-to-execute-fetch) but still can not figure out what the problem really is with my code.
Here is my service worker code

```
self.addEventListener("install", function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(preLoad());
});
var preLoad = function() {
    console.log("Installing web app");
    return caches.open("offline").then(function(cache) {
        console.log("caching index and important routes");
        return cache.addAll(["/", "/devotional-language-en-tab-9"]);
    });
};
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
    event.respondWith(checkResponse(event.request).catch(function() {
        return returnFromCache(event.request);
    }));
    event.waitUntil(addToCache(event.request));
});
var checkResponse = function(request) {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        fetch(request).then(function(response) {
            if (response.status !== 404) {
                fulfill(response);
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        }, reject);
    });
};
var addToCache = function(request) {
    return caches.open("offline").then(function(cache) {
        return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.url + " was cached");
            return cache.put(request, response);
        });
    });
};
var returnFromCache = function(request) {
    return caches.open("offline").then(function(cache) {
        return cache.match(request).then(function(matching) {
            if (!matching || matching.status == 404) {
                return cache.match("offline_en.html");
            } else {
                return matching;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

According to Chrome the error is mainly on this two lines  :

[image]

how to solve service_worker_en.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ? Please I need a specific answer that will solve the issue.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, the promise is "*a Request object that has already been used.*". In your case, you pass the same `event.request` to `checkResponse` as well as `addToCache`, both of which try to `fetch` it.

Comment: Can you please answer with a solution of how to clone it cos those I have done have failed so far. I did ```return fetch(request.clone())``` but it failed

Comment: Hm, unusual. Did you try that on both `fetch` calls? Maybe you did clone a request that was already sent - clone it before sending. Also, you probably should rewrite the logic anyway, and not make the same request twice in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **clone** the request object before fetch using `API_ENDPOINT.clone()`, since the object is already consumed.

```
var addToCache = function(request) {
  return caches.open("offline").then(function(cache) {
    return fetch(request.clone()).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.url + " was cached");
      return cache.put(request, response);
    });
  });
};
...
```

Comment: I just did that but I am still getting the same error message. https://www.iusefaith.com/service_worker_en.js

Comment: I have to award you the bounty even though it is not exactly what I want but so far you are the only one who gave an answer. Thank you